# Setting laravel to work on a port number?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express, laravel-4

I am working with nodejs, expressjs, and socket.io I am triggering events on my web app with a mobile phone over the nodejs server.

The app is built on javascript but I am using laravel to store data into a database. I am new to nodejs so I am pretty sure if I wanted, I think I could cut out php and just use the whole app with nodejs, but I don't want to. I like laravel and php and it's alread setup, so let me explain my problem.

laravel is installed on my server `http://example.com/public/` laravel's index.php is here. My routes for my data base resources are `http://example.com/public/feeds`. I can access this fine, but if I want to access my nodejs server I need to use `http://example.com:3000` which obviously causes a problem.

The nodejs/expressjs files are inside `http://example.com/public/MY-FILES-HERE` but since the nodejs dispatches on `http://example.com:3000` this throws my laravel routes off.

So what I am asking is how do I get it all to work well with eachother? I assume I need to setup a port somehow in laravel.

**EDIT:** So I am new to the port, and I didnt know there is already a default port set (80). My laravel install is on port 80, and inside here I can listen to calls from port 3000 using socket.io. I did not know that, so I have a page `http://my-server-ip:3000/test` which has one button and a script that sends the event to the nodejs server and that responds to my script which listens to events on port 3000 and executes a function. Cool stuff here, I hope I made sense I am very new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by

> this throws my laravel routes off

In a situation where you want to host multiple servers on port 80 from the same machine you might want to consider a reverse proxy. I recommend nginx for this.(http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy.html). Nginx will listen to port 80.

Then you setup a subdomain eg. node.example.com for the node.js service.

In the reverse proxy you listen for node.example.com on port 80 and direct that to port 3000. You set up Laravel/Apache? to listen on port 4000 and have nginx listen for www.example.com on port 80 and direct that to port 4000.

Is this what you are after?

Comment: What I mean when I say throws routes off is inside my backbone code when I fetch the resource it tries to get `GET http://my-server-ip:3000/feeds 404 (Not Found) ` being on that port I am not sure how I would fetch that resource or make POST/PUT requests on that.

Comment: I am trying to wrap my head around the above, I want to listen to the nodejs event dispatcher, using socket.io I can trigger a function from say `http://my-server-ip:3000/test` this has buttons and whenever a function is triggered the nodejs server listens to it and fires the request onto a page located at `http://my-server-ip:3000/`. I hope that made sense, I am just having a hard time merging it with a laravel project.

Comment: Its all in the same project location, laravel is installed inside the root of the domain, and the nodejs expressjs is installed within the laravel project. Does it sound like we are on the same page?

Comment: I am thinking put the laravel project inside the express project and set a route to the laravel directory?

Comment: After doing some reading, your post is starting to make more sense now. I didnt know default port was 80, so yeah laravel is listening to port 80, and my nodejs listens to port 3000.

Comment: So I should separate the projects. In my nodejs server if I had some code `var server = app.listen(3000); var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);` Inside my laravel project would I be able to `var socket = io.connect('http://162.243.220.45:3000');` use that and make a socket connection?

Comment: Oh so I moved the project up one level and it worked. Meaning my laravel project being on port 80 can still listen to requests from port 3000 as long as the code is in place.

Comment: You can absolutely have your websockets over 3000 and the rest of the app over 80, but you should keep in mind the many corporate firewalls  block all traffic over other ports than 80 and 443. So you might want to consider running it all over port 80 with reverse proxy if you want a wide coverage of clients.

Comment: Okay @col ill make sure to keep that in mind, I needed a quick dirty solution, it all worked out well. Since websockets are really gaining popularity I am sure I will use them in bigger projects and now I know to avoid using a port a higher than 80 thanks for the tip.